# .bashrc for Using GIt

Tags: git, bash

What is the .bashrc for using git that has these features. Something that shows you a lot of information but doesnt block you from viewing the terminal or distract you.

I have tried out Ultimate Bashrc and I love it, however I was looking for something with more features.

What it has to have:

- View of current branch and color coded
- User currently logged in on

Also, if there is something that will work with screen to show you what screen you are currently in and and all the ones open would really help be productive.

Comment: As per question guidelines, you should avoide things like "Best" in questions and titles. You should ask concrete questions which can be answered precisely :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this to show me which branch I'm on.

```
function git_branch() {
    tmp=$?
    branch=`git branch 2> /dev/null | awk '/\*/ { print substr($0, 3); }'`
    if [ "X$branch" != "X" ]; then
        echo -n "$branch "
    fi
    exit $tmp
}
export PS1="\[\033[1;37m\]\$(git_branch)\[\033[0m\][\u@\h:\w]\$? \\$ "
```